# Making table with small fonts but it gives me error

Tags: tables, texstudio

I try to use the following code for creating a table (Crosstabulation) but it gives me an error, which I don't understand. I'm relatively new to Tex and I would appreciate if someone can help me out.

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Association: discrete case}

\begin{table}[h]\footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{lccc} 
        \hline
            \textbf{Account Size} / \textbf{Recommendation} & No(=0) & Yes(=1) & Row Total \\ 
        \hline
         Large(=3)     & 34    & 18    & 52 \\ 
                       & 0.654 & 0.346 & 0.406 \\ 
                       & 0.493 & 0.305 &       \\ 
                       & 0.266 & 0.141 &       \\ 
        \hline
         Medium(=2)    & 22    & 23    & 45    \\ 
                       & 0.489 & 0.511 & 0.352 \\ 
                       & 0.319 & 0.390 &       \\       
                       & 0.172 & 0.180 &       \\ 
        \hline
         Small(=1)     & 13    & 18    & 31    \\ 
                       & 0.419 & 0.581 & 0.242 \\ 
                       & 0.188 & 0.305 &       \\ 
                       & 0.102 & 0.141 &       \\ 
        \hline
         Column Total  & 69    & 59    & 128   \\ 
                       & 0.539 & 0.461 &
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: You just forgot a `\\ ` before the very last `\hline`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sggestion: In addition to adding the missing `\\`, I have replaced the horizontal `\hline` s with the lines from the `booktabs` package, Added `siunitx` in order to improve the alignment of the numbers and used `makecell` to introduce a linebreak in the lenghty header of teh first column. With these changes, you can even increase the fnt size to `\small` and the table still fits into a `beamer` `frame`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Association: discrete case}

\begin{table}[h]\small
    \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=2.3]}S[table-format=3.3]} 
        \toprule
            \makecell[lc]{Account Size /\\ Recommendation} & {No(=0)} & {Yes(=1)} & {Row Total} \\ 
        \midrule
         Large(=3)     & 34    & 18    & 52    \\ 
                       & 0.654 & 0.346 & 0.406 \\ 
                       & 0.493 & 0.305 &       \\ 
                       & 0.266 & 0.141 &       \\ 
        \midrule
         Medium(=2)    & 22    & 23    & 45    \\ 
                       & 0.489 & 0.511 & 0.352 \\ 
                       & 0.319 & 0.390 &       \\       
                       & 0.172 & 0.180 &       \\ 
        \midrule
         Small(=1)     & 13    & 18    & 31    \\ 
                       & 0.419 & 0.581 & 0.242 \\ 
                       & 0.188 & 0.305 &       \\ 
                       & 0.102 & 0.141 &       \\ 
        \midrule
         Column Total  & 69    & 59    & 128   \\ 
                       & 0.539 & 0.461 &       \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]\footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{lSSS} 
        \hline
        {\textbf{Account Size} / \textbf{Recommendation}} & {No(=0)} & {Yes(=1)} & {Row Total} \\ 
        \hline
        Large(=3)     & 34    & 18    & 52 \\ 
        & 0.654 & 0.346 & 0.406 \\ 
        & 0.493 & 0.305 &       \\ 
        & 0.266 & 0.141 &       \\ 
        \hline
        Medium(=2)    & 22    & 23    & 45    \\ 
        & 0.489 & 0.511 & 0.352 \\ 
        & 0.319 & 0.390 &       \\       
        & 0.172 & 0.180 &       \\ 
        \hline
        Small(=1)     & 13    & 18    & 31    \\ 
        & 0.419 & 0.581 & 0.242 \\ 
        & 0.188 & 0.305 &       \\ 
        & 0.102 & 0.141 &       \\ 
        \hline
        Column Total  & 69    & 59    & 128   \\ 
        & 0.539 & 0.461 &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm learning.